# Translate a line in Java to c#

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, hashtable

I'm build an app in c# but I'm taking resources from a java code.

Check this java code:

```
public class Aclass{
    public Hashtable<String, BleDevice> meusBLEs = new Hashtable<String, BleDevice>();
}
```

BleDevice is another class.

In c# is something like this:

```
public Hashtable meusBLEs = new Hashtable ();
```

But without the parameters.

So, how I do it in c# (CSharp)

Comment: Its a poorly worded question but, I don't see why the down votes.  It should read something like whats the C# equivalent of Java's HashTable IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class that comes closest to a `Hashtable<TKey, TValue>` in C# would be [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, your declaration would be:

```
 public Dictionary<String, BleDevice> meusBLEs = new Dictionary<String, BleDevice>();
```

Comment: Dictionary is an equivalent java's hashtable?
Because the hashtable class exists in c#..

Comment: Yes in C# a Dictionary is a type of HashTable.  Dictionaries are used more frequently then Hashtables because Dictionaries give you type safety (much like your public Hashtable<String, BleDevice> meusBLEs definition in java) whereas the default HashTable class will allow insertion of any object.